# Is the “to” in “the first person to seriously consider” a preposition or “to + verb”?

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive

In this sentence,

> She's the first person in her immediate family **to** seriously consider getting it.

"to" is not used as "to + verb", right? If so, it is used as a preposition, but I am not sure how I should understand this sentence in that case.

Can I use "who" instead of using "to"?
Like:

> She's the first person in her immediate family **who** seriously consider getting it.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I think your analysis is mistaken. In the cited context, ***to*** is the "infinitive marker" associated with *[to] **consider***. As opposed to an inflected verb form *(She's the first one **considering** getting it)*, which *wouldn't* include that infinitive marker. You can't just replace ***to*** by ***who***, but you could rephrase to *(She's the first one **who is** considering getting it)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment looks like a full answer to me. Could you submit it as an answer?